# SQL Server hierarchical query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of users setup like this in SQL Server database

```
UserID  ReportsToUserID
1        NULL
2        NULL
3        1
4        2
5        2
6        3
7        5
...
```

Is there a way in SQL where I can get all the employees on the reporting chain. For example when I supply 1, I am expecting to get employeesID `3,6`

When I supply 2 I am expecting `4,5,7`

I do not know max number of chain it can go under

Comment: use a `recursive cte`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive CTE where you can set the `@Top` with either `NULL` for the entire hierarchy or with a specific `UserID`

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([UserID] int,[ReportsToUserID] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,NULL)
,(2,NULL)
,(3,1)
,(4,2)
,(5,2)
,(6,3)
,(7,5)
 
Declare @Top int = null --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 1 or 2

;with cteP as (
      Select UserID
            ,ReportsToUserID 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat('/',UserID,'/'))
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ReportsToUserID ,-1) else UserID end
      Union  All
      Select UserID  = r.UserID
            ,ReportsToUserID  = r.ReportsToUserID 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat(p.HierID.ToString(),r.UserID,'/'))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ReportsToUserID  = p.UserID)
Select Lvl   = HierID.GetLevel()
      ,UserID
      ,ReportsToUserID
      ,HierID_String = HierID.ToString()
 From cteP A
 Order By HierID
```

**Returns**

[image]

Now if @Top was set to 1

[image]

Comment: In the case where you're passing `NULL`, doesn't that just just return the entire table? If so, is there a benefit to having SQL go through all of the work to effectively produce a `select * from table`? In your example, I see that you're adding a synthesized path (which, incidentally, is directly cast-able to the `hierarchyid` DT), but that may or may not be warranted.

Comment: @BenThul Just to build the hierarchy (full or not) ... sorted and nested.